# Why am I getting a 404 status in my node.js app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, http-status-code-404

This is my ajax call

```html
  
          $.getJSON('/admin/users/search', {search:self.currentSearch}, function(results){
            
               self.users = results;

          })
```

and this is my route

```html
router.get('/search', async function(req,res){

  let users = await db.users.searchUsers(req.query.search);
  res.json(users);
});
```

Now I know that the route's URL only says search and not /admin/user, but that's because of how this app was set up.

Why am I getting a 404 with this?

Comment: would be helpful to see your router setup, since 404 (not found) really points to an issue related to a misconfigured router...

Comment: How is your router configured in your nodejs code?  Is it configured for `/admin/users`?

Comment: its not the configuration since I know that other functions in the same file work without having the /admin/user. I can't really say more than that since I was not the one who configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just a silly mistake. The url in the ajax call should have been /admin/user/search, but I accidentally had it as /admin/userS.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the solution.

```
router.get('/admin/users/search', async function(req,res){

  let users = await db.users.searchUsers(req.query.search);
  res.json(users);
});
```